# Unable to raise WLAN interface or start networking service

Tags: networking, systemd, network-interface, services, wlan

Sometimes (particularly lately) I encounter the issue detailed below. All the devices are accounted for, detected, and acknowledged by the system. I've been able to verify this using every method I can think of, including digging through system directories & files like `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices`, cross-referencing common tools like `lshw`, `lspci`, `lsusb`, etc. Any idea what's going on, and/or why? Cheers.

---

```
root@main:~# service networking start
```

```
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

---

```
root@main:~# systemctl status networking.service
```

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-08-12 12:18:03 AWST; 2min 48s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 30803 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 30800 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30803 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 12 12:18:03 main systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Aug 12 12:18:03 main ifup[30803]: Cannot find device "wlan2"
Aug 12 12:18:03 main ifup[30803]: ifup: failed to bring up wlan2
Aug 12 12:18:03 main systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 12 12:18:03 main systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Aug 12 12:18:03 main systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 12 12:18:03 main systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Please, post the content of your '/etc/network/interfaces' file. Besides that: Do you use network-manager?

Comment: @fragwürdig Okay, I will paste it when I get a chance. Anything in particular that I should be looking for? Yes, sometimes I use the `NetworkManager` service, but it tends to have issues when the `networking` service isn't running smoothly.

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and replace `auto wlan2` by `allow-hotplug wlan2`, if you already have your `allow-hotplug wlan2` line, then just delete the `auto wlan2` line. Worked for me just fine... and replaced `auto` by `allow-hotplug` for eth's too and works well.